# Responsive Web Design for Beginner

Tags: responsive-design

I am the beginner of Responsive Web Design. I have started with basic css coding for responsive such as max-device-width. I don't know how to start with body tag coding to complete basic layout.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your quesion, typically there's nothing special required for the body tag.

If you are new to responsive design, you could consider starting with one of the many frameworks, they will help you off to a fast start. A few suggestions are [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com) or [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com)

They are all good, choose one that suits your style and jump in!